# is there such a thing as a 120V XENON G6.35 bulb

Tags: halogen

We have a light fixture in the bathroom which takes 120V G6.35 halogen pin-style bulbs. Is there a XENON bulb in 120V in this size, and would it be compatible?

Comment: I don't think there is.  If it *does* exist, it will probably be for some obscure laboratory application at 300 watts and cost $1 million.

Comment: The closest to being able to find any matches was [here](https://www.bulbworks.com/advancedSearch.php?searchType=advanced&part_no=&attributeVOLTS=120&baseType=G6.35&advSearchCategory=&attributeWatts=&EQUIPMENT=&family=&attributeAmps=&Description=&itemType=&shape=&attributeBrand=&INDUSTRY=).  Note that their range voltage match doesn't work:  you have to select specific single voltages.

Comment: 1000bulbs.com has a superb selection, and all the G6.35 bulbs they have are 12v, 24v or 36v, except for two projector lights, at 150w or 250w, much too large to use in a bathroom fixture.  I would seek out the most common LED conversion bulbs that would plug into that fixture then convert the fixture to their voltage.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies, but I must revise my original answer.

There are "xenon" bulbs that are actually halogen bulbs filled with xenon gas. But what many consider to be a xenon bulb is an HID bulb filled with xenon. You must have a ballast associated with an HID light (halogens are not HID, there are no ballasts).

I cannot find a **120V xenon halogens** with a G6.35 base, either. I do see several 12V and 24V xenon halogen bulbs (OSRAM HLX); but otherwise, 120V xenon halogens have G8 bases (I don't think that OSRAM even has a G8 base; OSRAM does has a G8.5 base).

[image]

Since a xenon halogen bulb is generally lower wattage and has a lower operating temperature than halogen, you could probably retrofit the halogen lamp (if you absolutely love or need the lamp housing and are willing to go the extra mile to convert it to xenon) without needing to worry about the housing burning up. In such a case, I would recommend ordering a G8 base to retrofit your halogen lamp housing (but definitely make sure the xenon bulb that you purchase has a lower wattage than your current halogen, just to be safe). Also you need to make sure the G8 base can fit into your lamp housing, and that you are able to swap bases in your lamp housing. You should probably write a note inside the cover of the lamp regarding the change, including what was taken out... or better yet the actual specifications.

I also wonder about the alternative possibility of adding a transformer to convert 120V to 24V. Again you would need to pay attention to the wattage, especially with respect to an added transformer. For example, OSRAMS EHJ 64655 HLX bulb is a 10,000 lumen, 250 watt (10.4? amps x 24 V) bulb that might leave you blind and start a fire.

The real deal with halogen (incandescent bulbs) is that 99% of the gas is either argon, xenon, or krypton or a blend; and only 1% is actually halogen (usually iodine). The effect of using 99% xenon instead of argon is a minor improvement to the quality. In this case however, xenon is a little better than krypton or argon. Sometimes the manufacturer will use xenon and not even bother mentioning it (except in the technical data sheets like OSRAM's - [Xenophot® technology (HLX)](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1533645.pdf)), while other manufacturers will outright claim that they have a xenon bulb (and paint it blue, and increase the cost- it's sales pitch).

On the other hand, it is also fair to admit that a xenon HID bulb is actually just a metal halide usually (mercury) in xenon gas.

Comment: I think the original question is referring to Xenon _incandescent_ bulbs, not Xenon _HID_ bulbs. Xenon incandescents are directly  [interchangable](http://www.kitchenbathdesign.com/building/article/10428680/xenon-an-alternative-to-halogen-bulbs) with halogen bulbs, no ballast required.

Comment: Made an edit instead of commenting because my reply was too lengthy.

Comment: You're missing the big advantage of Xenon bulbs for home use -- they are a bit more efficient than Halogens, but they last much longer, up to [5 times longer](https://www.pegasuslighting.com/lc-lighting-info/xenon-vs-halogen.html) than a halogen bulb.